# How to fix foreach in treeview

Tags: c#, events, treeview

I am doing my treeview remove button event by this tutorial:
[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNIZDLFPmXE)

I did everything same as shown in tutorial:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RemoveCheckedNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
        }
        List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        void RemoveCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in nodes )
            {
                if (node.Checked)
                {
                    checkedNodes.Add(node);
                }
                else
                {
                    RemoveCheckedNodes(node.Nodes);
                }
                foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
                {
                    nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
                }
            }
        }
```

But it throws me error in foreach saying : An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in project_TreeView.exe

Also what is very weird, everything works with last Node. So I guess my foreach isn't working. Any ideas?

> EDIT:
> So I found this is working, If I am removing last and before last node. How to make it, that I could remove any node(For example first and last)

Thanks.

Comment: Try to debug it and find out which object is null. It could be that `node.Nodes` is null, In this case a null refrence exception will occure on  `foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)`

Comment: Yes it says node is null, how to fix this?

Comment: And why this foreach working only with last and before last option, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the search for checked nodes into a separate method. So you first find all nodes and then remove them.

At the moment your code would try to remove the same nodes several times (on each recursive call of RemoveCheckedNodes, even if you move the loop out of the other loop, the remove is still called multiple times.

Also I would use a local variable for the checkedNodes list. Your list is not cleared, so it will contain items which are already removed.

This way its more easy to debug, if your problem is finding or removing the nodes:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      RemoveChecked(treeView1.Nodes);
  }

  void RemoveChecked(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
  {
      foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in FindCheckedNodes(nodes))
      {
        nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
      }
  }


  private List<TreeNode> FindCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
  {
      List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>()
      foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
      {
        if (node.Checked)
        {
          checkedNodes.Add(node);
        }
        else
        {
          // find checked childs        
          checkedNodes.AddRange(FindCheckedNodes(node.Nodes));               
        }
      }
      return checkedNodes;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day :)

Comment: youre welcome :-) please upvote the answer if you found it helpful. ty

Answer (score 1):

The second foreach should be outside of the first.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveCheckedNodes(treeView1.Nodes);
    }
    List<TreeNode> checkedNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    void RemoveCheckedNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes )
        {
            if (node.Checked)
            {
                checkedNodes.Add(node);
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveCheckedNodes(node.Nodes);
            }
        }
        foreach (TreeNode checkedNode in checkedNodes)
        {
            nodes.Remove(checkedNode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, foreach loops are read-only iterations, I think you should use for loops to remove objects from a collection.